# Run JUnit test on utilities class method that contain Android package

Tags: android, junit

guy, I'm new to Android testing.

I would like to know is it possible to test the following method in `JUnit` test?

or it has other best practice to test this kind of android specific **without running emulator**.

```
public class NetworkUtils {

    private final Context context;

    public NetworkUtils(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether network connectivity exists and it is possible to establish
     * connections and pass data.
     *
     * @return flags indicate the network connectivity ready or not to make connection.
     */
    public boolean hasNetworkConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and use `Robolectric`, which mocks/stubs Android APIs for unit testing purposes, but in honesty I would question whether this is the kind of logic you **should** attempt to verify in a unit test.

The reason I say this is because everything inside that method is Android framework specific, and why should you be responsible for testing Android framework code?

In my opinion, you should attempt to separate Android functions like this from your own business logic, something you have control over, and simply mock the responses you expect if it succeeds or fails. This would mean you wouldn't need to test this method directly, but instead test its effects (i.e. `whenNoNetworkConnection_thenSomethingHappens` and `whenNetworkConnection_thenSomethingElseHappens`).

For that I would recommend the `Mockito` library.